# How custom UIView handle screen rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, screen-rotation, uianimation

For some reason, i make a custom view, override it's drawrect menthod, to draw some string and img. just something like:

```
@implementation WaterMarkView

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSLog(@"drawRect");

    NSString* test = @"This is a test string";
    NSDictionary *dict = @{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:22],
                           NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0],
                           };

    NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16], NSFontAttributeName, nil];
    CGSize strsize = [[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:test attributes:attributes] size];

    CGRect screentBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    [test drawAtPoint:CGPointMake((screentBounds.size.width - strsize.width)/2,
                                  (screentBounds.size.height - strsize.height)/2) withAttributes: dict];
}


@end
```

Add it to an a viewController

```
....
WaterMarkView* view = [[WaterMarkView alloc] init];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.view addSubview:view];
....
```

it works fine.

However, when the screen rotation, it will clearly see the string transition is not smooth but ugly.

When i add a UILable whith string, it will transition smooth when screen rotation

What can i do to make a custom UIView transition smooth when screen rotation?

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `contentMode` to `UIViewContentModeRedraw`, the default mode `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill` will scale the content.